# How firebase charge when cloud function response not all returned query data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image: Example]

What if I execute cloud function to query to firestore and it return data to cloud function, then cloud function process those data and return only some result, how cost firebase will charge me?

Are firestore and cloud function always located in the same place? How could I make sure that I will not be charged egress network bandwidth if firestore and cloud function are not in the same area?

[image: pricing table]